# USB_SERVICE cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android

I am trying to send a byte stream to an arduino board from a service and a part of the code

```
if (deviceFound == null) {
   UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
  }
```

says that "USB_SERVICE cannot be resolved or is not a field". I tried google-ing it but with no luck.

Comment: Try a clean build.  If that doesn't work, make sure your target SDK level is at least 12 (when USB service was added).

Comment: Tried to clean the project. Still didn't work. Also the min SDK level and target SDK level are 21 and 23